# MS Band sdk page refresh

Tags: sdk, microsoft-band

Has anyone gotten the page refresh in the newest release (1.3.10702) of the Band sdk to work?  I still have to exit and go back in the tile to see a page refresh.  Running VS 2013 and Windows 8.1.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  Refresh the windows phone and band firmware.  This can be accomplished by installing the Microsoft Health app (not to be confused with the Health and Fitness app) on the phone, then it will request to update to the latest version.